Why isn't it generally recommended to alter both the temperature and `top_p` when calling GPT?
I read  on platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create:

We generally recommend altering [the temperature] or top_p but not both.

Why isn't it generally recommended to alter both the temperature and top_p when calling GPT?

It is recommended to alter the temperature & top_p both because :
Temperature: This parameter controls the randomness of the model's output. Lower temperatures (e.g., 0.2) make the output more deterministic and focused, often sticking closely to the highest probability next words.
top_p: This parameter, also known as probability mass, limits the model's sampling to the smallest possible set of words whose cumulative probability is at least p. For example, if top_p is set to 0.9, the model will only consider words that, together, makeup 90% of the probability mass. This can result in more coherent and contextually relevant text, as it avoids the tail-end probabilities.
By adjusting these parameters we can have control over the llm output so that we can generate more accurate and deterministic responses.
